# how to order groups by count in solr

Tags: solr

I'm wondering how to order groups in a Solr result. I want to order the groups by `numFound`. I saw how to order the groups by score **[here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=sortspec&titlesearch=Titles#Request_Parameters)**, but that didn't seem to actually make a difference in the examples I looked at, and isn't exactly what I wanted.

In the xml you can see the number per group as `numFound` and that is what I want to sort the groups by, so for example I could see the largest group at the top.

```
<arr name="groups">
<lst>
<str name="groupValue">top secret</str>
<result name="doclist" numFound="12" start="0">
...
```

Any tips appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on the numFound is not possible as numFound is not an field in Solr.
Check the [discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-groups-by-numFound-group-size-td3315740.html) mentioning it not being supported and I did not find a JIRA open for the issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but it **is** possible with two queries.

First query: bring back the field you're grouping by as a set of facets for your navigation state. You can limit the number of records returned to 0 here: you just need the facets. The number of facets you return should be the size of your page.

```
group_id:
     23 (6)
    143:(3)
      5:(2)
```

Second query: Should be for the records, so no facets are required. The query should be an OR query for the facet field values returned from the first query. (group_id:23 OR group_id:143 OR group_id:5 and so on) and be grouped by the id you are used for grouping.

Sorting: reorder the records from query 2 to match the order from query 1.

That'll do it, with the proviso that I'm not sure how scalable that OR query will be. If you're looking to paginate, remember that you can offset facets: use that as the mechanism instead of offseting the records.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible since the last time I looked into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by using fields

consider an Example :

If you have 5 FACETS and COUNT associated with it.
Then you can sort by using the COUNTS of each fields.

It can be applicable to normal/non-facets fields .

```
public class FacetBean implements Category,Serializable {



private String facetName; //getter , setters
private long facetCount; // getter , setters


public FacetBean(String facetName, long count,) {

    this.facetName = facetName;
    this.count = count;
}}
```

Your calling method should be like this

```
private List<FacetBean> getFacetFieldsbyCount(QueryResponse queryResponse) 
{
    List<FacetField> flds = queryResponse.getFacetFields();
    List<FacetBean> facetList = new ArrayList<FacetBean>();
    FacetBean facet = null;
    if (flds != null) {
        for (FacetField fld : flds) {
            facet = new FacetBean();
            facet.setFacetName(fld.getName());

            List<Count> counts = fld.getValues();

            if (counts != null) {

                for (Count count : counts) {
                    facet.setFacetCount(count.getCount());
                }
            }
            facetList.add(facet);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(facetList,new Comparator<FacetBean>() {

        public int compare(FacetBean obj1, FacetBean obj2) {

            if(obj1.getFacetCount() > obj2.getFacetCount()) {
                return (int)obj1.getFacetCount();
            } else {
                return (int)obj2.getFacetCount();
            }
        }
    });

    return facetList;
}
```

In The same [URL](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=sortspec&titlesearch=Titles#Request_Parameters) They have mentioned something like.

sort  -- >ex : For example, ***sort=popularity desc*** will cause the groups to be sorted according to the highest popularity doc

group.sort -- > you can apply your field here .

Hope it helps.